# How to interpret the results of the R pnorm and analogous functions?

Tags: r, distributions, probability, quantiles

The help for the `pnorm` function states:

It says that `pnorm` gives the "distribution function", but it seems that it gives the quantile,

for example, `pnorm(q = 0, 0, 1)` returns `0.5`, which suggests that `q=0` refers to the 50th quantile of a N(0,1). I understand what the "normal probability density function" is, but not why `pnorm` is called a 'distribution function'.

The `R` help says that the `q` argument is a "vector of quantiles", but it appears in practice that `q` represents an observed value.

What I want to know is: if I observe '2', what does `pnorm(2)` say about my assumption that it came from a N(0,1) distribution?

Comment: Not all distributions have a density function. *All* of them have a [cumulative distribution function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function) (CDF), which thereby deserves to be called "distribution function."  Everything else can be derived from it.  In particular, its *inverse* is the [quantile function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile_function).

Comment: The statement "R help says that the q argument is a `vector of probabilities` ..." is incorrect. The documentation under ?pnorm clearly says that the argument q is a vector of quantiles.

Comment: @atiretoo I have fixed this typo, but I am still confused about why `pnorm(q=2)` would work if `q` is a quantile.

Comment: A [percentile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentile) is a *value* of a variable corresponding to a certain *percent* (which is a value of the cumulative distribution function).  Thus the `q=2` in an expression like `pnorm(q=2)` refers to a *value of a standard normal distribution.*  The result, 0.977 = 97.7%, says that 97.7% of a normal distribution lies at or below $2$.

Comment: What is 50th quantile? Median? If so 0.5 is definitely not the median of $N(0,1)$ distribution.

Comment: @mpiktas I see where the statement was unclear, and I have clarified that I meant "`q=0` is the 50th quantile"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`pnorm` gives you the cumulative probability distribution at a specified value of $x$.  This is the cumulative probability for a standard normal distribution. So in your example, the quantity I call $x$ is specified as $0$ and $0.5$ as the answer is $P[X\leq 0]$ for a random variable $X$ with a $N(0,1)$ distribution. If you took $x=1.96$ you would get $0.975$ because a standard normal distribution has a probability of $0.025$ in the upper right tail above $1.96$.

Comment: So, if I want to calculate the two-tailed probability of observing x from a standard normal, it would be `ifelse(pnorm(x) > 0.5, 2*(1-pnorm(x)), 2*pnorm(x))`? I was hoping for something a little more straight forward; perhaps that there is another base function for that.

Comment: You mean the probability of observing a value greter than x in absolute value. By symmetry that would be 2(1-pnorm(x)).

Comment: I do not understand the difference between your point and mine - isn't that exactly what a two tailed probability _should_ do in the case of a standard normal? I am trying to generalize this so that it will work for a generic distribution (normal or otherwise), so perhaps using a `N(0,1)` is confusing my point.

Comment: Maybe your code is doing what I said.  I took exception with the incorrect statement that this represents "the two-tailed probability of observing x from a standard normal". It looks to me like pnorm will work specifying other means and variances than 0 and 1 respectively. To get the cumulative distribution for a general probability density would require integrating the density from minus infinity to x which in many cases would require numerical integration as it does for the normal.

Comment: Michael: your `2*(1-pnorm(x))` only makes sense for non-negative  $x$

Comment: as @Henry points out, it should be `2*(1-pnorm(abs(x)))` or `2*pnorm(-abs(x))`

Comment: Yes you are both right.

Comment: Or `2*pnorm(abs(x),lower=FALSE)` ... all of these come up with the same answer. The answer by @Abe is less efficient because it calls pnorm 3 times to get the same result. I wonder if the OP regards 'the two tailed probability of observing `abs(x)` or greater as the answer to  "what does pnorm(2) say about my assumption ..."? A strict answer to the question as posed is *nothing*.

Comment: @Macro: Your second version should be much, *much* more accurate if the absolute value of $x$ is of any appreciable size.